Why can't NotificationListenerService connect when downloading apk on Xiaomi Android 13,14 device? I tried some apps on CH Play but they didn't work
Why can't NotificationListenerService connect when downloading apk on Xiaomi Android 13,14 device? I tried some apps on CH Play but they didn't work. It fails on xiaomi and redmi series. It already has the BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE Permission
Can you give me a Solution?
